# Is the “When you want Truth the way you want air, you will find it.” anecdote part of historic philosophy, or just an urban legend?

Tags: history

> A Greek philosopher was standing in water and asked a man, “What do you want?” and the man said, “Truth!” Then he held him under the water and asked again, “What do you want?” He said, “Truth!” Then he held the man under water until he almost passed out, and let him out, and asked, “What do you want?” The man gasped, “Air!” The philosopher said, “When you want Truth the way you want air, you will find it.”

Is this anecdote historical, and if so what sources did it derive from and what was the original version? If it’s just an urban legend, are there any pages addressing it as an urban legend?

Thanks,

Comment: The story doesn't sound Greek, or even European. It has an air of the metaphysical power of the will to it that seems more Oriental than Occidental. Outside of Christianity (which started as an Oriental religion), Occidental thought tends to be more fatalist: humans are helpless flotsam in the roaring rapids of events; what you desire does not matter at all.